# Snoke's ship weapons

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

So the weapon that was used against the fleeing transports when

> Admiral Holdo used the hyperspace ramming to destroy Snoke's ship?

The weapon fired a green laser beam and it arched.
What's the weapon called?

Answer (score 3):

The film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition) indicates that the Supremacy is armed with two gigantic **turbo-laser cannons**.

> Veins of illumination ran along the kilometers of its surface to a
> central command area the size of a major metropolis. And **it was armed
> with giant turbolaser cannons** from bow to stern—on both sides.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi: Expanded Edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

There's a nice description of how normal turbo-lasers function [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183432/why-are-turbolasers-called-lasers-when-they-appear-to-be-scaled-up-blasters/183442#183442). Presumably the ones on Snoke's flagship are much the same, just *scaled up*.

Comment: Why do the bolts move in curves? There's no gravity field deflecting the bolts 'down' in the plane of the ship.

Comment: @ifly6 - The entire chase takes place against the backdrop of a nearby star system. Perhaps that star was close enough to cause the bolts to curve slightly.

Comment: does explain the battle of endor :) that was in close proximity to a gas giant