# Do lightsaber blades/blaster bolts cast shadows?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Do lightsaber blades and/or blaster bolts cast shadows? (I know it's possible to see a blade's shadow on the ground during Episode VI, but that was clearly due to technical limitations, not intentional.) I'd appreciate an answer that lines up with the canon, please.

Comment: I would think not since they cast a light of their own.

Comment: @DarthVader Being a light-casting entity doesn't preclude you from casting a shadow.

Comment: Why do people think that plasma is transparent??   Plasma is made of excited gas and it is in fact **opaque** to light at the frequencies that it emits.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Obviously! Otherwise, Jedi wouldn't be able to fall to the Dark Side! ;)

Comment: @DarthVader Actually, [humans really *do* literally glow light](https://www.livescience.com/7799-strange-humans-glow-visible-light.html), which should have been another tip that emitting light does not preclude an object from casting a shadow.

Comment: @GhotiandChips WHAT?!?!??!?!?!?!!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!!??!?!?!?!?!?!?!!?!!?!??!!? That is all I have to say about that.

Comment: Anything blocks light cast a shadow if it don't blocks light it's transparent, so if it's not transparent it cast a shadow. Trick is when it also emits light it's light can mask the shadow. Think about the two Tatooine suns, one cast a shadow over the other light

Comment: Although this does not answers the question for the star wars universe, light emitting objects (like a flame) have a shadow, hence if the situation is the same, then a laser sword should have a shadow.

Comment: It would. Even glass, which we generally conceive of as transparent, doesn't transmit light perfectly, and therefore, casts a shadow.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From this image from *Episode I* would appear that they do cast shadows, though the angles don't look quite right to me.

[image: Qui-Gon Jinn vs Darth Maul]

From Season 1 Episode 14 of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, "Defenders of Peace",  Ahsoka's lightsaber clearly casts a shadow. This is animated and so is not the result of a mistake on post production forgetting to remove a prop's shadow.

[image: Ahsoka cuts down some droids]

The above example comes from the verified Facebook page [Star Wars: The Clone Wars](https://www.facebook.com/StarWarsTheCloneWars/photos/a.350962014943099.76071.328988200473814/722150521157578/?type=1&theater) and has the following description (emphasis mine).

> When Ahsoka cuts down droids inside the Separatist base in season one episode Defenders of Peace, she is shown in silhouette and her lightsaber casts a shadow. **Contrary to online debate, there's nothing wrong with this. Lightsabers do indeed cast shadows; anything that is opaque does.** Try it with a fluorescent light tube.

Blaster bolts on the other hand would appear not to cast a shadow as we see when Kylo Ren halts a blaster bolt in *Episode VII*.

[image: Kylo Ren halts a blaster bolt]

Again in *Episode II* there appear to be no shadows coming off of the blaster bolts.

[image: Droids fire on the drop ships]

---

Some out of universe reasoning here is that the bolts are added in with effects whereas the lightsaber blades are full props used in the fighting and so will cast a shadow.

Comment: If there were a sufficiently bright enough source of light above the blaster bolt, it might have casted a shadow. Since this occured at night time, there simply wasn't enough light for a shadow to be created. 

Out of universe, you can see the actor on the right has a shadow from a backlight.

Comment: I bet that the shadow's weird angles are because they use a green screen and the lighting came from a different angle than what the in universe sun would have.

Comment: The shadows are from them using broomstick handles for lightsabers in the prequels.

Comment: @GhotiandChips `whereas the lightsaber blades are full props used in the fighting and so will cast a shadow.`

Comment: "This is animated and so is not the result of a mistake on post production forgetting to remove a prop's shadow."

That's not necessarily the case, depending on how the scene was created (technology and production process). They might actually have created the shadows the same way you'd have done it with actual props; Have them stand before an actual light source and record the shadows cast on the wall. The animator could easily have made the light sabers not cast any shadows of course, but it's entirely possible they didn't think too hard about whether or not they should.

Comment: @Cubic Of course I was just over simplifying things for ease. Though it's likely more of a conscious decision to show the shadows here than in the main series. Especially given the scene is all shadows so it would appear to be even more on purpose.

Comment: @DarkSkyForever Added another image for the blaster bolts in a brighter area and there still appears to be no shadow.

Answer (score 90):

If we assume that lightsabers and blaster bolts are some kind of plasma, they should cast a shadow under the right circumstances. Stars are big balls of plasma and one star can block the light of another, such as in an [eclipsing binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_star#Eclipsing_binaries). Flames, which include a small amount of plasma, can also cast shadows, either by absorbing some of the light or refracting it due to currents of heated air.

[image: Image of the shadow of a flame from Robert Frost's Quora answer.]
<sub>[Quora, Why doesn't a fire or a flame cast a shadow, while other things around it do? If there is no shadow, does it mean light can pass through it, even though flame is not transparent?](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-a-fire-or-a-flame-cast-a-shadow-while-other-things-around-it-do-If-there-is-no-shadow-does-it-mean-light-can-pass-through-it-even-though-flame-is-not-transparent/answer/Robert-Frost-1)</sub>

Shadows are formed when there is something between a distant light source and a surface blocks some of the light. However, if the object blocking the light, like a lightsaber, is emitting light itself, the shadow will only be obvious if the distant light source is much brighter than the light-emitting object.

Plasma strongly absorbs light, but also strongly emits light. However, if you have a strong enough light source, you should be able to see a shadow from a lightsaber or blaster bolt.

Comment: Not only brightness, also color plays a big part! A red lightsaber will cat a shadow in a room with blue lights - most of the room will be blue the surroundings of the lightsaber will be violet and the shadow will be red.

Comment: @Falco well, that’s still “brightness”, just with different values for the individual color bands.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with the star wars universe? This is totally unrelated to the canon, and wrong as proven by the answer below. Furthermore, the OP has clearly asked for an in-universe, canon answer.

Comment: @Edlothiad Which answer below? The one with in-universe photos proving that they do cast shadows, or the ones with the assumptions and guesses?

Comment: The one with the strong canon backing, while the conclusion above may have been "They might cast some shadows", the method it used to reach there is off-topic to the question and in my opinion, to the site.

Comment: They don't cast shadows in the three movies that matter. But they should've. +1

Comment: @Falco That's incorrect.  Just because something emits red light doesn't mean it only absorbs non-red light.  Also, even if that were true, I believe red-tinted glass under a blue light should have a black shadow, since it blocks the blue light.

Comment: @BlueRaja you misunderstood, the plasma blocks all external light - so would cast a black shadow. But the blade is emitting red light itself, which will color everything red. Thus the shadow will be an area where the room-light is blocked, but the light from the blade itself is visible.

Comment: @Falco `the surroundings of the [red] lightsaber [in a room with blue lights] will be violet` I think you mean [magenta](https://www.d.umn.edu/~mharvey/colorwheel.jpg)

Comment: The candle flame in the illustration demonstrably DOES cast a shadow.  Just not much of one.  Because gas, even hot gas, isn't very opaque.

Comment: @LaurencePayne: I think you must have misunderstood something. This answer is using that illustration in order to show that the flame casts a shadow; so there's no need to reply saying so.

Answer (score 2):

In Legends a lightsaber wasn't really the same thing as a blaster bolt. In fact, in Legends the explanations of lightsabers have changed from source to source. One interesting example I will link, at 3:35 it shows that lightsabers are far more solid than just magnetically contained plasma. This would support the shadows seen in the films and shows as more than just a result of the limitations in filming.

Blaster bolts have always been described as plasma and would likely obey the rules of our known science and not cast a shadow unless particularly outshone by another light source. I can't think of any visual examples of this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This is a decent answer (would be better if it was Disney canon of course). However, it would be better if you could include the relevant parts of the video into your answer, I don't want to watch a 5 minute video to look for a 1 second clip of a shadow. Lastly, don't forget to take the [tour]

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The timestamp appears to be included in the answer already. The description of what happens at that point could be a little clearer, but it looks okay to me.

Comment: @F1Krazy Somehow missed the timestamp, edited the link to start at the right point now though :)

Comment: I don't think this shows solidity, just the strength of the forces keeping the beam intact (along with Satele's http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tutaminis ability).

Comment: @Mathew-Read, Its the way the blade begins to crack or at least react to the amount of force being applied that doesn't appear to be just a magnetically contained plasma.  I don't think pure energy would crack like that. It's the only time I've seen anything like it and it's not really canon anymore, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

There would be many factors involved. Mainly the intensity of secondary light source that is hitting the blaster bolt or blade, distance to surface that a potential shadow would be cast upon, the direction of travel from the light source (is it focused in one direction or being cast out in all directions), as well as the frequency of the light from the source, the blade, and/or the blaster bolt.

[This link](http://wtamu.edu/~cbaird/sq/2015/12/01/can-a-fire-have-a-shadow/) talks about how any light source that contains mass is technically able to have a shadow when certain criteria are met. All that is needed to create a shadow is to block or redirect light.

So technically the answer would be yes assuming that a lightsaber blade or blaster bolt is more than just a source of light but actually plasma or some other form of matter undergoing a reaction. But to get further into an explanation of the exact requirements to cause this shadow, one would have to make assumptions about the intensity and frequency of both a lightsaber blade and a blaster bolt. So the answer is absolutely that yes, they would in the right situation cast a shadow but attempting to determine that right situation is not scientifically possible without an actual real world example.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This seems to be merely a yes answer with not much evidence, do you have any to add? Lastly, don't forget to take the [tour]!

Comment: edited answer to include reference.

Answer (score -1):

Lightsabers are Plasma beams and have almost no mass. [explained here](https://www.google.com/search?q=do%20lightsabers%20have%20mass&oq=do%20lightsabers%20have%20mass&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.10183j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
But I have very little knowledge of how plasma and light interact.

The out of universe answer is that they used props of solid objects therefor casting a shadow.

I would guess that a lightsaber might have the capacity to cast a shadow, if the light it's casting is much less the light it's blocking.

Edit:
There is a helpful explanation on plasma [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/404774/can-plasma-cast-a-shadow)

Comment: Your link is to a google search.  And "we have very little knowledge of how plasma and light interact." seems like a strange claim to make, plasma is very well understood.

Comment: "we have very little knowledge of how plasma and light interact." ??? What? It's a false statement.

Comment: I meant that I have little knowledge, but I miss spoke. @GhotiandChips

Comment: You don’t need to know much about the interaction of plasma and light. There is a simple rule of thumb: if you can’t look through it, it can cast a shadow.

Answer (score -1):

I think that neither lightsabers, nor blaster bolts cast dense shadows, but they may and probably do cast a poor shadow. Why I think so? Take for instance a laser from real life, it won't cast a dense shadow since most light will go through it. A lightsabers will probably block some of the light too, but most of it will go through.

Comment: This may be a better answer if it read as an answer. Though I don't really see what it adds on to what is already here.

Comment: Lasers don't cast shadows at all. You need to get way to the gamma range to get any measurable interaction between photons, visible light just isn't anywhere near energetic enough. Plasma is very different - it both absorbs and emits light readily (thanks to all those free electrons).

Comment: @Luaan My shop laser casts a barely seen shadow, so your statement is wrong.

Comment: Really? How did you measure that? And why do you think the laser casts the shadow? If there is any real optical effect (and not just an illusion), it probably has to do with how the laser interacts with the air in the room - most likely by changing the optical properties of the air, causing light to bend and producing areas of higher brightness and correspondingly lower brightness - not casting a shadow. Unless you consider lenses concentrating (or dispersing) light as casting shadows.

Comment: Blaster bolts in Star Wars are ionized plasma, not lasers.

Comment: @TylerH How do you know?

Comment: @SovereignSun It is a well-established principle; see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13702/why-do-blaster-bolts-move-slower-than-the-speed-of-light for one example.

Comment: As Luan said, a laser will at most distort light, not shield it, so it's not a shadow. Even that would require a very strong laser, best tuned to 760 nm ([absorption line of oxygen](https://doi.org/10.1029/JD095iD11p18577)), so you actually heat the air significantly. No consumer-available laser will do that.